# How to search and replace in vim in the reverse direction

Tags: vim

I have a large file with a bunch of 0's like:
000000000
00000000

How can I achieve search and replace in the reverse direction? If I want to replace 0000 with 0011, then the output of the operation should be:
000110011
00110011

Comment: Are the right ends of the blocks of zeroes anchored at all? In your example, the first block is ended by a space. The second could be at end of line. Or is it not that predictable in your actual file?

Comment: End of the block is not predictable, it can be 1 or more spaces or end of line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't substitute in reverse direction. One trick to do it (in your case) is to give a pattern which searches four zeros, ending **without** other zero.

I'm sure there is better, but the following deals about this trick:

```
:%s/\v\zs0000\ze(0000)*([^0]|$)/0011/g
```

It matches four zeros (`\zs0000\ze`), followed by an optionnal sequence of n*4 zeroes (`(0000)*`), **followed by anything but a zero** (`([^0]|$)` : character, or eol)

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux? In that case, here is a handy solution:

- reverse each line (with `rev` external command)
- apply your pattern (after having reversed it)
- restore the right order for each line

You should give it a try step by step:

```
:%!rev
:%s/0000/1100/g
:%!rev
```

Hope it can help.